# General concepts of lines and planes

Tags: analytic-geometry

I've come across an exercise that asks the reader to state the correct answer. For me, the only one right is the third, but I would like to know why the first one is not correct also:

> The line $r$ is parallel to the plane $\alpha$, but is not contained
>   in it. Choose the correct alternative:
>
> - The are, in $\alpha$, lines that are perpendicular to $r$
> - All lines in $\alpha$ are parallel to $r$
> - There are, in $\alpha$, lines that are parallel to $r$ and lines that are skew to $r$
> - Line $r$ cannot be coplanar to any line in $\alpha$
> - Every plane that contains $r$ is parallel to $\alpha$

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is correct. Regarding the first point, we call two lines perpendicular if they are coplanar ans intersect in a right angle. As the lines in $\alpha$ do not intersect $r$, ...